# Dividing the data in multiple columns to 8 values logically in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the data as following. Each column starting from `1.07m` to `11.82m` represents the depth and the values corresponds to the temperature. I am interested in reducing the datasets into 8 sets (8 distinct water depths). While doing so I would like to use the averaging method. For example in row1 of my data starts from column `x1.07m` to `x2.82m` (x2.82m because all the values beyond that point are `NA`). I would like to create a separate data frame with data and 8 columns (layer1, layer2, layer3, layer4, layer5, layer6, layer7, layer8). Layer1 value should start from `1.07m` and the Layer8 should correspond to the maximum non-zero value.

Data: The dput of data can be found on https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9267938/rcode.R

```
> head(data.frame(mytest))
             datetime Year Month Day Hour Minute Second       X1.07m       X1.32m       X1.57m        X1.82m       X2.07m      X2.32m       X2.57m       X2.82m     X3.07m
1 2014-08-03 12:40:00 2014     8   3   12     40      0 -0.079553637 -0.018856349 -0.022559778 -0.0278269427 -0.019816260 -0.01304108 -0.003394041 -0.010720688         NA
2 2014-08-03 12:50:00 2014     8   3   12     50      0 -0.001409806  0.006434559  0.013885671  0.0033940409  0.009665614  0.01176982  0.011130125  0.019991707 0.02997477
3 2014-08-03 13:00:00 2014     8   3   13      0      0 -0.006942835 -0.011130125  0.010715907 -0.0058745801 -0.005716650  0.01534520  0.030355206  0.024851408 0.04862646
4 2014-08-03 13:10:00 2014     8   3   13     10      0 -0.020586547  0.002935416 -0.016304143 -0.0001326389 -0.003896694  0.00361282  0.004723244  0.013947785 0.03787721
5 2014-08-03 13:20:00 2014     8   3   13     20      0 -0.028394300 -0.023132719 -0.001721911 -0.0139650391 -0.038460075  0.01749898  0.008466864  0.003630492 0.01442467
6 2014-08-03 13:30:00 2014     8   3   13     30      0 -0.034646511 -0.006791177  0.004064423 -0.0038792422 -0.015942808 -0.02029747 -0.014287663  0.007956902 0.01786172
      X3.32m     X3.57m      X3.82m     X4.07m      X4.32m       X4.57m       X4.82m        X5.07m       X5.32m      X5.57m      X5.82m       X6.07m X6.32m X6.57m X6.82m
1         NA         NA          NA         NA          NA           NA           NA            NA           NA          NA          NA           NA     NA     NA     NA
2 0.05094966 0.04699597 0.032100892 0.02650842 0.045689389 0.0169759192 -0.006879327 -0.0187681077 -0.030404344 -0.04405705 -0.04501967           NA     NA     NA     NA
3 0.04500833 0.01713256 0.006450535 0.02870071 0.019079580 0.0009741734 -0.024666588 -0.0409943643 -0.030201313 -0.03873463 -0.02893064           NA     NA     NA     NA
4 0.03971244 0.05723497 0.039496306 0.03799276 0.012742073 0.0024111385 -0.023706420 -0.0188563490 -0.033791404 -0.04162619 -0.02979164 -0.045051204     NA     NA     NA
5 0.03269076 0.05125416 0.054766084 0.03625076 0.005988487 0.0020217180 -0.007510352 -0.0069913419 -0.006656083 -0.01630414 -0.01403812 -0.001580609     NA     NA     NA
6 0.01913708 0.03932811 0.048955209 0.04764632 0.037480601 0.0205218532  0.004171715  0.0009371753 -0.002468609 -0.04511612 -0.01263816  0.035861544     NA     NA     NA
  X7.07m X7.32m X7.57m X7.82m X8.07m X8.32m X8.57m X8.82m X9.07m X9.32m X9.57m X9.82m X10.07m X10.32m X10.57m X10.82m X11.07m X11.32m X11.57m X11.82m
1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
2     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
3     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
4     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
5     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
6     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

Sometimes the data points will be 20, 22, 25 points so the function should be written such that it would try to account those information and divide into 8 data values for each rows.

## Rcode.R linked to dropbox has the code that has dput of mytest. It was pretty big to be posted here. So I posted a external link.

### Info added

Each row would have different number of data. The motive is to convert them into 8 columns of data using averaging or linear interpolation.

Comment: So what does your desired output look like? Regardless, the first step is probably to melt to long form, e.g. `mytest %>% gather(depth, value, -datetime:-Second)` with `tidyr`.

Comment: Agreeing to @alistaire: or use `reshape2::melt()`, so that you simply will not have the lines (in long format dataset) that correspond to those `NA`s.

Comment: Oh, you can add `na.rm = TRUE` to get rid of those. I'm not sure if they're important to the desired end product, honestly.

Comment: @Alistair I already removed the points that have NAs. Now what I need to do with the remaining data is to have exactly 8 different points. For the first row there are 8 data points so I don't need to do anything.  However from second row, I need to do averaging or interpolation to have 8 points representative of 8 different heights. If my initial depth is 1.07 and final depth is 6.2, then I want to divide that region into 8 subregions and have values for them.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the question as a desire to collapse the values to means of eight equally spaced depths, `dplyr` and `tidyr` take us where we need to go:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mytest %>% 
    # melt to long form
    gather(depth, value, -datetime:-Second, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
    # clean depth to number
    mutate(depth = extract_numeric(depth)) %>% 
    # group so cut levels are for each datetime
    group_by(datetime) %>% 
    # group to keep columns; cut depth into 8 levels per group
    group_by(datetime, levels = cut(depth, 8, paste0('level', 1:8))) %>% 
    # collapse groups by taking the mean
    summarise(value = mean(value)) %>% 
    # re-spread new levels to wide form
    spread(levels, value) %>% 
    # re-add other time columns dropped by summarise
    inner_join(mytest %>% select(datetime:Second), .)

# Source: local data frame [20 x 15]
# 
#               datetime  Year Month   Day  Hour Minute Second       level1        level2
#                 (time) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)  (dbl)  (dbl)        (dbl)         (dbl)
# 1  2014-08-03 12:40:00  2014     8     3    12     40      0 -0.079553637 -0.0188563490
# 2  2014-08-03 12:50:00  2014     8     3    12     50      0  0.006303474  0.0065298277
# 3  2014-08-03 13:00:00  2014     8     3    13      0      0 -0.002452351 -0.0057956151
# 4  2014-08-03 13:10:00  2014     8     3    13     10      0 -0.011318424 -0.0001388374
# 5  2014-08-03 13:20:00  2014     8     3    13     20      0 -0.017749644 -0.0116420430
# 6  2014-08-03 13:30:00  2014     8     3    13     30      0 -0.012457755 -0.0133731725
# 7  2014-08-03 13:40:00  2014     8     3    13     40      0 -0.020440875 -0.0253538846
# 8  2014-08-03 13:50:00  2014     8     3    13     50      0 -0.058681338 -0.0177194127
# 9  2014-08-03 14:00:00  2014     8     3    14      0      0 -0.037929680 -0.0211918383
# 10 2014-08-03 14:10:00  2014     8     3    14     10      0 -0.027045726 -0.0147261076
# 11 2014-08-03 14:20:00  2014     8     3    14     20      0 -0.048997399 -0.0290804019
# 12 2014-08-03 14:30:00  2014     8     3    14     30      0 -0.059110466 -0.0370898043
# 13 2014-08-03 14:40:00  2014     8     3    14     40      0 -0.067156867 -0.0138750287
# 14 2014-08-03 14:50:00  2014     8     3    14     50      0 -0.049762164 -0.0280648246
# 15 2014-08-03 15:00:00  2014     8     3    15      0      0 -0.028033559 -0.0245379952
# 16 2014-08-03 15:10:00  2014     8     3    15     10      0 -0.044087211 -0.0107995239
# 17 2014-08-03 15:20:00  2014     8     3    15     20      0 -0.028761973 -0.0113161242
# 18 2014-08-03 15:30:00  2014     8     3    15     30      0 -0.013476051 -0.0142316424
# 19 2014-08-03 15:40:00  2014     8     3    15     40      0 -0.012799297 -0.0135366710
# 20 2014-08-03 15:50:00  2014     8     3    15     50      0 -0.012238548 -0.0180806876
# Variables not shown: level3 (dbl), level4 (dbl), level5 (dbl), level6 (dbl), level7 (dbl),
# level8 (dbl)
```

Note that you should check that these data make sense in context; you've lost your depth data by scaling them.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. I will look into the results and let you know if these data make sense in context.